# Pipe output of shell command (!) into a new buffer in Vim

Tags: linux, vim

How can I pipe the output of a shell command into a new buffer in Vim?  The following obviously wouldn't work, but you can see what I'm getting at:

```
:!echo % | :newtab
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826003/how-do-i-dump-output-of-an-external-command-to-a-new-buffer-in-vim

Answer (score 40):

You can't pipe the output of a shell command into a command that creates a new buffer, but you can create a new buffer and read the output of a shell command into that buffer with one entry on Vim's command line. A working version of your example would be

```
:tabnew | r !echo <c-r>=bufname("#")<cr>
```

Note that the pipe symbol in this case is a separator between Vim ex commands, not the shell's pipe. See also

```
:help :tabnew
:help :r!
:help :bar
```

Comment: That's almost exactly what I need, just the other way around so that I can access the filename of the current buffer. Note: updated the question to hopefully clarify the desired end result.

Comment: @Richard Marquez: i updated this answer. the new tab is now opened with the "old" filename, thus you could call :!echo %

Comment: But not `:r!echo` without altering the buffer.

Comment: @Luc Hermitte: right, i ll rollback.

Comment: @garyjohn, akira: thanks for the help. The "<c-r>=..." part made Vim spew errors, but I was able to get it working with ":tabnew | r !echo #".

Comment: Might also be useful to note that if you want to map this to a key in your .vimrc, you'll need to replace the | character with <bar>.

Answer (score 30):

Here's what I do.  It's alluded to in comments in the above answers.

```
:new | r ! <cmd>
:new | r ! <cmd> #   (# is replaced with filename)
```

**Example 1**: Find all text files in `/tmp`

```
:new | r ! find /tmp -name '*.txt'
```

**Example 2**: You're editing file foo.txt and you want to run `ls -la foo.txt` and get the output in a buffer:

```
:new | r ! ls -la #
```

The `#` is replaced with the filename of the original buffer you're editing.  This is particularly useful for ad-hoc source control commands e.g.

```
:new | r ! hg annotate -un #
```

`:new` creates a horizontal split, use `:vnew` if you want a vertical split instead and `:tabnew` for a new tab.

Comment: Are you able to answer this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45223626/outputting-shell-command-edited-buffer-into-a-new-buffer-in-vim-e499-empty-fil) as well? it is about trying to use the current buffer with `%` for the next buffer but E499.

Comment: can this be done without a leading newline?

Comment: I figured it out `:new | 0r !ls ^@ $,$d` where `^@` is `<CR>` entered using `CTRL-V` `CRTL-J`

Answer (score 5):

```
:tabnew | enew | r ! <your shell cmd>
```

works for me.

Answer (score 4):

If you really require to store the result in a new buffer, but require info from the old current buffer, then you can either use `system()`:

```
:let res = system('echo '.expand('%'))
:tabnew
:put=res
```

or store the current buffer name for *later*:

```
:let bn = expand('%')
:tabnew | :r!echo <c-r>=bn<cr>
```

Comment: see the other answer, you can do it without storing the name in a variable. but good answer anyway.

Comment: Indeed. I wasn't sure '#' will give the expected result in that case -- as I never use tabs

Answer (score 0):

@Ciro Santilli linked the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3826018/9306292

```
:enew | .! <command>
```

If you want to keep your configuration simple, use one of those:

```
<C-w>v / <C-w>s / yourtabkeybinding, ie <C-w>t
```

and then

```
:%!command
```